# UITableView not showing Up in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am building a project without storyboard. Everything is working fine but I can't seem to figure why I can't add `tableView` programmatically. I have tried the same code for adding `tableView` in another empty project and its working fine but inside my project the tableview is not showing up. My view hierarchy is like below.

I have a BaseClass like this:

```
class BaseController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setupViews()
    }
       func setupViews(){

     }
}
```

Then I have `firstViewController` class inherited from `Base Class`:

```
class firstViewController: BaseController
```

Inside my `firstController`, I am declaring and initializing my tableView:

```
var tableView:UITableView = {
    let tbl = UITableView()
    tbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tbl.backgroundColor = .blue
    return tbl
}()
```

Then I am overriding `setupView()` inside `firstViewController` here like below:

```
override setupView() {
 
     view.addSubview(tableView)

     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)

    ])  
 }
```

It should show empty tableView cells but it is not showing up. I guess there is something to do with the base and derive class thing but I can't figure out the exact problem.

Comment: There are some typos above but I think the issue is your trailing constraint is set to the leading anchor so it's  a zero width view.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake, you got it right sir !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `trailing` constraint for tableview correctly.

```
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
```

You were setting `view.leading` to `tableview.trailing` that makes your tableview invisible from current view.